# PL/SQL exception and Java programs

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, exception

Business logic is coded in pl/sql packages procedures and functions.
Java programs call pl/sql packages procedures and functions to do database work.

pl/sql programs store exceptions into Oracle tables whenever an exception is raised.

How would my java programs get the exceptions since the exception instead of being propagated from pl/sql to java is getting persisted to a oracle table and the procs/functions just return 1 or 0.

Sorry folks i should have added this constraint much earlier and avoided this confusion. As with many legacy projects we don't have the freedom to modify the stored procedures.

Comment: You can read the stacktrace of the exception if you are using CallableStatement to fire the pl/sql procs.

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.CallableStatement throws java.sql.SQLException.  If your stored proc throws an exception, your Java code will know about it.  The code that calls the stored proc will have to handle this exception.

You have a choice: you can either have the stored proc throw the exception or have the Java code check the return value and query the table for the exception if the error code is returned.

But the exception isn't "lost" either way.  You get it from the JVM or the table.

I vote for the JVM because it's easier.  Less PL/SQL code, less Java code.

Comment: Duffymo thanks for responding on a Sunday :-D
The pl/sql block throws exception but that gets persisted to a table and then it returns 1 or 0 and the actual exception gets lost

Comment: @YogoZuno - correct.  Don't have your stored proc catch the exception and persist it to a table.

Comment: would be great if someone could explain why duffymo was down voted this is insanity

Comment: I re-read the original post, and I can't see anything that says the stored procs can't be edited.  When somebody says they have business logic in stored procs, I assume that they wrote them.  How YogoZuno can be "fairly certain", without more intimate knowledge of the project, is well beyond me.

Comment: I don't believe the question would be getting asked if the original poster could simply change the stored procs...

Comment: "Sorry folks i should have added this constraint much earlier and avoided this confusion. As with many legacy projects we don't have the freedom to modify the stored procedures." - turns out you were correct, but there was nothing explicitly said until three hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't change the PLSQL code, you'll have to monitor the table. And of course, that will only work if the error table stores some sort of session or use identifier.

Comment: why was this thread down voted yogozunos option is a legitimate one

Answer (score 1):

"is getting persisted to a oracle table"
You could create a trigger on that table that rejects the insert. For example, if the error table contains an 'ERROR_DESCRIPTION' column, you could have a BEFORE INSERT ON error_table FOR EACH ROW trigger which does a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,:NEW.ERROR_DESCRIPTION)

When the PL/SQL code goes to log the error, that will fail with the replacement error and that will, if you are lucky, get propogated to the Java layer.

It is an ugly hack, but if you truly can't change the code, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you use a framework that supports aspects, it would be easy to make an aspect that checks for the exception in the appropriate table. If not, then you could write something similar to this code:

```
        ResultSet exRs = null;      

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(normalSql);
            exRs = statement.executeQuery(exceptionSql);
            exRs.next();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connection.rollback();
        }

        if (null != exRs.getString(exceptionColumn))
            connection.commit();
        else
            connection.rollback();
```

Sorry I couldn't be more specific.

Comment: Azder thanks for the response however the code you gave me would not be applicable in a situation where a stored proc is involved is that correct ?